# How to create users on AWS with an initial password

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, aws-cli

I need to create a lot of new AWS users.

I would like to generate their usernames from their email addresses:

```
Example@gmail.com -> username: example
```

and give them a default password that they will be able to change when first logging in. Once the user is created, all users should be put into the same group to have the same permissions.

**Is there a bash script or python with which this process could be automated?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use AWS CLI for bash or AWS SDK (boto3) for python to automate this task. 
Here's what you'll need to do:

1. Read emails either from file or database.
2. Use SDK **create_user** function to create new IAM user. Visit the link for doc [link](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/iam.html).
3. Use SDK **get-login-profile** function to create password for user with password reset on login flag. Follow the [link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/iam/create-login-profile.html#examples). Note: It'll give console access to user.
4. Add user into specific group using SDK. Follow the [link](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/iam.html#IAM.Client.add_role_to_instance_profile).

Ref:

> https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_users_create.html#id_users_create_cliwpsapi